# How to cancel a customer's subscription in Stripe.net - they update too often

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments

I first used stripe back in 2015.  It was easy, then I figured it out (kind of) in 2018/19.  But now I'm trying again on an older project and am completely stuck.  I'm using checkout.js because I can no longer figure out managing the card, and I can create a customer, add them to a subscription, and even retrieve the customer id.  I can pull back customer details, but I can't figure out how to update their subscritpion - specifically how to cancel it.  I've updated the metadata aspect after trying for a while on understanding the API, but it doesn't seem to affect the next invoice.  Here is my current approach:

```
        StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey("testkey");
        var customers = new CustomerService();
        var charges = new ChargeService();
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var user = db.Users.Single(x => x.Id == userId);

        var customer = customers.Get(user.CustomerId);
        var sub = customer.Subscriptions.FirstOrDefault();
        sub.CancelAtPeriodEnd = true;
```

Somehow I need to update here??

Then this is back to where I just clear out my user.

```
        user.CustomerId = null;
        user.Paid = false;
```

It's not too pretty right now, but I just don't get this.

Another approach is this:

```
var service = new SubscriptionService();
var options = new SubscriptionUpdateOptions {
  CancelAtPeriodEnd = true,
};
Subscription subscription = service.Update("subid", options);
```

But I don't understand how this ties to the customer and their customerid.

Comment: The last approach you showed is the correct way to go. That will update the Subscription to cancel at the period end. A customer with ID `cus_xxx` represents the customer each Customer can have zero or many Subscriptions, each with `sub_xxx` IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you try deleting the custumer? or is not your objective delete it?

```
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc";
var service = new CustomerService();
service.Delete("cus_H01wAPhnLalFWf");
```

In the API ref guide says: Also immediately cancels any active subscriptions on the customer

Comment: I'd wondered about this, but does it not make sense to leave the customer for reporting, or am I thinking about this incorrectly?  Thanks for the help.  I will try this.